# How to define Flutter app structure that is based around lists of strings?

Tags: string, flutter, list, dart, listview

I want to develop a simple app with a few screens:

1. List of items that user can select. (7 items)
2. Sub-list of items based on the value selected in the first screen (another 5+ items for every 7 items from the first screen)
3. Simple screen showing some strings and two images based on the value selected in the second screen.

What is the best way of defining those values in terms of Flutter best practices?

Right now I have a list of strings in my main.dart (first screen):
`List<String> menuItems = <String>[ "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3" ];`

When one of the items is pressed by the user, index of the selected ListTile is passed to the second screen (list_screen.dart).

And now I don't know what is a best way to go from here. Should I declare 7 lists in that file for every item that can be selected in the first screen? And then in the third screen declare next lists for both strings and images? This seems like a mess and will result in long files with the actual widget declarations preceded by a huge number of list variables.

Or is there a better way to store the structure for that kind of app? In Android native I was doing that using arrays in .xml files. Maybe creating separate .dart files for every screen's data is the right way?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest learning about State management (bloc, Cubit, Provider) those are the top 3 libraries, I like cubit because it is simple and straightforward, now, storing variables can be done in 2 different ways, you can store them in XML or JSON file and set it ina assets older, then you parse the data in the controller class. or, you can store them as lists in the controller (cubit file) and let the three screens read from this cubit file and react to the changes made by the controller. you can use a local database also.
I hope I answered your question .